# How to properly change DNS without changing emails?

Tags: dns, smtp, web-hosting

I have a little problematic situation. I have a domain registered in one place and dns for this domain is hosted on another hosting company. The problem is that i dont have access to that hosting and I need to change hosting to new one. I know that I can easily change NS records in registrar company so then i can manage dns in new hosting. But here is the problem. I have emails already set on old hosting and it have to be like that for now. 
So my question is - if I will change NS to new hosting, and then I will set MX to the old hosting (the same from MX lookup), then my emails configured in old hosting will remain functioning? 
Remember that I dont have access to that old hosting. I am connecting to that emails through smtp and pop3.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as long as the value of MX records remains the same, there won't be any issue. ITs just that DNS will resolve from the new servers and will receive same output.

> Please ensure you put all records including TXT records with exact
>   same value for no interruption.